# FORTRAN "random" segmentation fault after reading data in text file

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

For the last few days I have been facing a very strange problem in my FORTRAN code, which represents a chemistry-network solver.

I have a text file with the following structure as part of the inputs for my model

```
! Chemistry Scheme from Lellouch et al. (2012) 
! Modified 13-06-2016. For more info see "Introduccion de quimica en el codigo de transpote vertical 1D II", pp 20-28
1           ! number of reactions. Do not forget to update

! H + H2O --> OH + H2;               R001 
'M1006--0701'           ! Descriptor 
7.5e-16                 ! proportionality constant A, sec^-1, cm^-3  sec^-1, cm^-6 sec^-1 
-1.6                    ! fitting parameter n 
-80.81208               ! Activation energy (KJ/mol) 
' '
' '
'end'
```

In which as more reactions are getting involved, they are just piled up next to the other separated by an ' ' and the integer of "number of reactions" is updated with its number.

I have been working with this structure for a year and it never gave me problems. Recently I incremented such network with > 50 reactions (the exact number is not very important as I will explain), then this error displays on my terminal.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F4C0DB72777
#1  0x7F4C0DB72D7E
#2  0x7F4C0D4C4CAF
#3  0x41D3FB in __subroutines_MOD_klosses
#4  0x44B768 in __iteration_MOD_losses
#5  0x44DEBE in __iteration_MOD_updating
#6  0x44DD60 in __iteration_MOD_solving
#7  0x44E0A1 in __iteration_MOD_iterating
#8  0x4014B7 in MAIN__ at temporalDiffusion1.1v.f:?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My experience in FORTRAN tells me there is a problem with indexes and arrays where I store information. Something plausible since the subroutine devoted to distribute the chemistry information is "messy" in the sense there is lots of string handling which in FORTRAN I always find it kind of troublesome.

But after checking the code intensively, I recognize indexes are suddenly changed after some array manipulation which should not encompass a bigger problem. Here is an example of how indexes are strangely modified as it is printed on the terminal

```
 before :          11          10 M1310--14                          1
 after :          11          10 M1310--14                          1
 ------
 before :          14          10 M1810--16                          0
 after :          14          10 M1810--16                          0
```

The rightmost integer represents a number which will be used as index of another array. Since in FORTRAN these integers start from 1, hence I have this weird error. Next, the piece of code involved in the previous printing

```
    print*, "before :", lpTerms(molIndex)%losIndM(i),
 *               molIndex, theDecRates(Mindex)%label,
 *               lpTerms(10)%losIndK(1)
        lpTerms(molIndex)%losTermsM(i,:) =      
 *                        theDecRates(Mindex)%cM(:)*nProfile(:) 
    print*, "after :", lpTerms(molIndex)%losIndM(i),
 *               molIndex, theDecRates(Mindex)%label,
 *               lpTerms(10)%losIndK(1)
```

As you see, it is a basic multiplication not even involved with the integer being suddenly modified. Besides, there is a certain amount of iterations before the error crawls up, so this is not an immediate problem.

The most strange thing is that this is totally unnoticed if the chemical network is "small". Basically the last statement is not completely exact, some times I can run for 51 reactions, other for 50. Particular reactions when removed does not seem to be the solution.

I use gfortran to compile the code.

What's going on here?

Thank you very much if you have read up to the end of this question!.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and, *most importantly* ,  read [mcve]. Wee need the actual code and we need to see the variable declarations and all important context in the code, not just a few lines. Compile your code for debugging, like `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall` and report the full program output. We need to see the error messages and the output generated before the error. The error can be somewhere else then you think. It can be an out of bounds array access somwhere else in the code.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF for the suggestions. I have solved the problem after exploring the outputs using those flags you suggested me. Lots of warnings appeared but what has shown to be the biggest help was when running the program itself, with these options it was more restrict and I could solve weird index troubles that I think were the main actors in this segmentation fault . Thanks for the welcome too!

By the way, next time I will try to be more concise with the code, but this time I thought it was to big. Just the chemistry network input is about 600 lines.